# Why does self.view call subview setter method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, subview, setter

I have a custom view controller with several subviews. Each of those subviews is connected to the view controller's .m file via IBOutlet properties. Those subviews have custom setters that adjust size of the other subviews depending on whether that subview is or is not displaying content.

Now it seems that these custom setters are being called by `initWithCoder:` prior to `viewDidLoad` being called. (I hope/assume this is normal.)

My issue is that calling `self.view` accesses the setter methods for self.view's subviews. My current understanding is that this should not be necessary. Can someone explain what's going on here? I'd rather this not happen as I'm not intending to set anything by accessing `self.view`.

Here is the code: https://github.com/kenmhaggerty/Sandbox

Comment: what custom setters? did you override UIView's property setter/getter such ash `setFrame:`?

Comment: I created three properties of form `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *viewOne` within my view controller, and each view has a corresponding custom setter of form `- (void)setViewOne` in which I adjust the size of the other views depending on whether I set `viewOne` to something from nil or to nil from something.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a sample of the code that you wish not to be called by accessing the `view` property (wow, this is strange)

Comment: Okay I added the upload to GitHub to the original post. (I still have no idea how to use GitHub... :S)

Comment: Seems half your classes and some associated resources didn't come over when you committed.  Try to put the .git files in the top level directory of the XC project, and make sure resources and files are being copied to the project dir and not just added as references to something on your hard drive alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling self.view on a view controller causes it to load its view from the nib, if it hasn't already done so. This instantiates all objects in the nib (using initWithCoder:) and sets the values of any outlets (using your accessor methods). It then calls viewDidLoad, by which point everything in the nib will exist.

Your outlet setter methods are probably not an appropriate place to be making layout adjustments. Either use a constraint-based layout which will automatically adapt to changes in size of the subviews, or use viewDidLayoutSubviews, or use the methods you are using to pass model information to those subviews.